# Variant to Scripting Dictionary performance loss

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I stumbled upon a performance-Bottleneck in my Project, that i would like to improve, but i do not quite understand why its behaving like it does.

The bottleneck is part of a [JSON-Parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON), that translates Dictionaries and its content to JSON-Text. The function takes Variants, checks its type and translates accordingly like so:

```
Function parseToJSON(itemToParse As Variant) As String

Select Case VBA.VarType(itemToParse)
    
    Case vbString
        '...
        
    Case vbInteger
        '...
        
    Case vbObject
        
        'If item is Dictionary
        If TypeOf itemToParse Is Scripting.Dictionary Then
                
            'Loop through items
                Dim key As Variant
            For Each key In itemToParse.Keys
                
                'Parse each item (Call oneself with item)
                Call parsetojon(itemToParse(key))
            Next key
        End If
    
    ' . . .
End Select


End Function
```

The Bottleneckis the `itemToParse(key)` that is sent when the function calls itself, where the item of the dictionary is accessed, which i nailed down by testing the isolated parts of the code with timed massed calls.

My suggestion is some kind of implicit typecheck of the variant, but i dont know. Thanks for ideas and ask if something is unclear and i will try to explain better. Still learning how to ask efficiently

Comment: do you need the dictionary's `key` in that branch?  If not you could just iterate through the `.Items` instead.  Or maybe copy the `.Items` into an array and then increment through that.

Comment: If this is making changes/suggesting to a open source project, perhaps it makes sense to add a performance issue in github.

Comment: FYI use of `Call` is unnecessary and outdated

Comment: @RyanWildry yea good point, will do. @RBarryYoung I tried it and it improves the performance by 1/3 if i copy the `.Keys ` and `.Items` to a `Variant` variable first and iterate through them. Interestingly if i copy them to a `Variant()` array variable the performance worsens by 1/3 again for some reason. but only on `.Keys`, `.Items` doesnt care if its copied to `Variant` or `Variant` :D

Comment: @Brattamob, here's optimized parser for JSON: [VBA - JsonIO](https://gist.github.com/florentbr/e89b6b77ede7cb92367698d86c830b20).  And an custom [Dictionary](https://gist.github.com/florentbr/0488726f5bc22657319d52f49dbb0c62) which will outperform the orginal one when used on large data sets.

Comment: very nice work, thank you sir. i tested it and it sure is an improvement. your modules are approximatly 1.5 times faster!  know yourself thanked :*